# getView method not called, ArrayAdapter inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I have used custom `ArrayAdapter` but `getView()` methods for same is not being called.
However, I've checked with `getCount()` method, it's returning `value > 0. 2` In my case.
Here is a code snippet for my Adapter.

```
public class ProfilesSwipableAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SoundProfile> {
private final ArrayList<SoundProfile> cards;
private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Context mContext;

public ProfilesSwipableAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SoundProfile> cards) {
    super(context, 0, cards);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.cards = cards;
    //this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final SoundProfile card = cards.get(position);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_profile, parent, false);

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(getMapURLBlack)
            .into(((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.map_lite)));

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtProfileName)).setText(card.profileName);

    view.findViewById(R.id.imgEdit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                buildAlertMessageNoGps();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("name", card.profileName);
                intent.putExtra("key", card.mKey);
                intent.putExtra("lat", card.latitude);
                intent.putExtra("lng", card.longitude);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setMessage(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.prompt_discard_profile))
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                            list.add(card.mKey);
                            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, list);
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profiles").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(card.mKey).removeValue();
                            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ProfileDeletedEvent(position));
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

@Override
public SoundProfile getItem(int position) {
    return cards.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cards.size();
}
```

}

I'm initializing this Adapter from Fragment. 
I've checked that ArrayList I'm passing has `items > 0` too & `adapter.getCount returns > 0` as well, so not sure what happening wrong here.
Here is code snippet for that.

```
profilesSwipableAdapter = new ProfilesSwipableAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_profile, profileArrayList);
            swipeCardView.setAdapter(profilesSwipableAdapter);
```

**What's really frustrating to me is if I follow the same steps through Activity, I'm getting the correct results i.e. `getView()` of Adapter is getting called.
What can be wrong?**

Comment: I think your Adapter is fine (because you said it's working without the Fragment), so we need to see how you set up the Fragment.

Comment: Nothing fancy to setting up fragment, this is how I'm calling it. `ProfilesFragment profilesFragment = new ProfilesFragment();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_Content, profilesFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();`. And in on createview, `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profiles, container, false);
mContext = getContext();
 swipeCardView=(SwipeCardView)view.findViewById(R.id.card_stack_view);`

Comment: If you're still looking for help, please post enough code so I can reproduce the problem. Then I'll run your code and try to find the error.

Comment: I got it working. I was assigning adapter after ArrayList is filled. Instead, I assigned the adapter with empty ArrayList and when ArrayList is filled I just notified the adapter and everything started working like a charm. Not sure why so, but it's working!

Comment: You're right, this seems weird. But good to hear you've fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 /Just try to use below code Snippet/

 Put the below code below onCreateView of Fragment

 Activity mactivity;
 MainActivity main_activity;

Note: MainActivity --> is Activity on which Fragment is Attached.


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mactivity = getActivity();

    main_activity = (MainActivity) mactivity;
 }

 And then try to use "main_activity" instead of getActivity() in
 below code. 

profilesSwipableAdapter = new ProfilesSwipableAdapter(main_activity, R.layout.list_item_profile, profileArrayList);
        swipeCardView.setAdapter(profilesSwipableAdapter);
```

Comment: Didn't worked, Got "ClassCastException" for    `main_activity = (MainActivity) mactivity;`.

Comment: Note: MainActivity --> is Activity on which Fragment is Attached.
have you use your that Activity only on which fragment is attached